# duplicated values in lookup edit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I'm using a devexpress lookup edit in a winforms application.I got many duplicate rows in  the Database and those same values appear in the LookUpEdit control.

[image]

Is it possible to get the distinct values in the lookup edit datasource without deleting those rows from the Database.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you do so far? Please show some code

Comment: Change your query to get only distinct values. How are you getting your data from the database? What is your datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Before binding your table to grid or other deXpress control, try to create a view out of the table and apply `RowFilter` ( filter condition) on it.

Eg:

```
DataView view = new DataView(yourTable);
DataTable distinctTable = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);
```

Now you can bind the `distinctTable`  to your control

Comment: I'm getting my data from a view not from a data base table